# Method for differentiating between a location search and a 'regular' search?

Tags: php, search, location

We have items in our database which are tied to locations. THese items also have titles (names). We would like one search bar to allow users to search for generic locations which ca be geo-coded (probably via Google maps API), or allow users to search for items by name (Title).

Is there a library, API, or general way of differentiating between a location and a "normal" (non-location) search?

We currently test for zip code vs name - since zip code is relatively easy to test for vs a string match.

This feels like an exercise in machine learning, which I'm not prepared to do :D

Comment: What's wrong with just performing both?

Comment: Check for address first using Google or similar API:

http://gabesumner.com/address-validation-using-the-google-maps-api

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - We provide a different result type if its a search result vs a name result (Sort by distance from entered location, vs relevance search by name). However it might be possible.

Comment: @ernie - Thanks, something like that might be possible. I'm worried about false-positives from google maps api, however, as Google tends to try to give results for addresses no matter how irrelevant. (Searching a name could easily generate a location or many different locations for gmaps api)